# Can we download the 9.x version of postman for mac?

Tags: postman, version

I am seeing few download links for postman 9.x version Windows version but not able to find anything for mac apple chip. Does postman allow the downloads for older versions for mac?

Answer (score 2):

Found [`the answer to your question`](https://community.postman.com/t/direct-download-link-for-9-x/29148/4) on the Postman Community with a direct link to version 9.x for windows and mac.

Here is the answer provided

Direct download links for v9.31.28 (last version before 10.0)

[`Windows`](https://dl.pstmn.io/download/version/9.31.28/win64)
[`Mac Intel Chip`](https://dl.pstmn.io/download/version/9.31.28/osx)
[`Mac Apple Chip`](https://dl.pstmn.io/download/version/9.31.28/osx_arm64)